# Axios post request not sending parameters

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a scipt tag in which im making a post request to a route through axios.Axios is not sending the parameters through.
Here is the code for axios:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

const data={'firstName':"sai"}

    axios({
      url: "/",
      method: "post",
      data: data,
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
```

Here is the express side of things:

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
   console.log("post route");
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Im console.logging the data coming from the post request with the help of req.body(I also have body-parser working just fine.Tested with other normal forms).The req comes through to hit the post route.BUt the body is empty always logs "{}".
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Define config object

```
let config = {
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  } 
}
```

Mandatory: Use array for params and not js object for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('PARAM1', 'VALUE1');
params.append('PARAM2', 'VALUE2');
```

Call post

```
 axios.post( uri, params, config )
```

or

```
 axios({
     url,
     headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
     data: params
 })
```

**Option 2:**
Create an api instance (optional) and set default content-type

```
const api_local = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost:1000/myapi',
});
api_local.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

Mandatory: Use array for params and not js object for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('PARAM1', 'VALUE1');
params.append('PARAM2', 'VALUE2');
```

Call post

```
 api_local.post( uri, params )
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also have body-parser working just fine.Tested with other normal forms

Normal forms submit data encoded as either `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Axios submits data, by default, as `application/json`.

You need a different body parser. One which supports JSON.

(Or to [submit the data in a different format](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format))

Comment: i tried "content-type":"multipart/form-data"   didnt work

Comment: @EaGLE – Putting a claim that you are sending multipart/form-data in the headers will not change the format of the data you are sending.